# New NSWindow with NSTableview crashes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a very simple project.  Extremely watered down.  All it does is load some text into an NSTableView.  That's it.  But it's using a new window and controller, called "Revisions."

As soon as the new window becomes active, it crashes or just locks up.  No errors in the console.  If it sits in the background, behind the AppDelegate's window, it appears to load the information fine.  I can see the table is populated perfectly. But as soon as I click on the window and make it active, it crashes/locks.

This is driving me nuts.  I know it has to do with memory management, but I can't figure out where or how or why.

Note, I'm in XCode 4.2, where there's no more releasin' (unless I change some settings, of course).

All connections in

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Revisions.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{    
    Revisions *rev = [[Revisions alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Revisions"];
    [rev loadWindow];    
}
```

Revisions.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Revisions : NSWindowController
{    
    IBOutlet NSTableView *quicktimesList;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *unusedDataList;   
}

@end
```

Revisions.m

```
#import "Revisions.h"

@implementation Revisions


- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];    
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    NSLog(@"Creating number of rows.");
    return 10;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Starting Loop.");
    NSString *words = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Row %i", rowIndex];
    NSLog(@"Looping %i", (int)rowIndex);
    return words;
}

@end
```

Comment: “I know it has to do with memory management…” On what grounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I'm going to give you a couple of tips when dealing with potential memory leaks in Xcode 4.2.

1. When writing software for Mac it is advisable to enable garbage collection in your build settings. Just simply search for "garbage collection" in the search bar of your build settings and set it to "required".
2. If you have memory leaks in your project just press the "product" menu and hit "Analyze".This does as the menu item states, it analyses your project for potential memory leaks and helps you track them down.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did it, Johann!  Thank you so much.  If you have a second, can you send me a link of a good source for things I should be looking out for in XCode 4.2?

Comment: I would recommend that you just search google for things that you are unsure about regarding Xcode 4.2. There are multiple questions concerning Xcode 4.2 functionality, including many sufficient answers.

Comment: Why is it “advisable to enable garbage collection”? Why not enable ARC instead?